# R program for returning value from a vector through index

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have written a function to return the hospital name for minimum mortality rate for a diseases, but its not giving me desired output, can any one please check the code and tell me whats wrong in it ?

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
tab <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
attack <- as.numeric(tab[,11])
failure <- as.numeric(tab[,17])
pneumonia <- as.numeric(tab[,23])
hospitals <- as.vector(tab[,2])

diseases <- c("heart attack", "heart failure","pneumonia")

if(!state %in% tab$State){
    stop("invalid state")

}
else if(!outcome %in% diseases){
    stop("invalid outcome")
}
else{
    if(outcome == diseases[1]){

        min <- min(attack, na.rm = TRUE)
        index <- which(attack == min)
        hospitalname <- hospitals[index]
    }
}

hospitalname
}
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your problem without some sample inputs and outputs. I think you should be able to get something working using `dplyr` and the `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

else needs to be used slightly different. It can not start a new line instead have each else statement like...

```
if(){
blah...blah...
} else {}
```

This should help. Without testing scripts and a description of the intentions it is hard to assist.

Comment: I tried that, but I am always getting output as [1] "NYU HOSPITALS CENTER". ## even if I change the name of state in function best's argument

Comment: I need to return name of the hospital which has least mortality rate for heart attacks, Hospital.name is second column in my table and mortality rate for heart attack is 11th column